# Fiction series where each book takes place in a new world

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a series I read as a teen where each book takes place in a new 'world'; the only two I remember are I think the 4th and 5th books where one takes place in a city on the water and one in a world where everyone sleeps in a virtual reality chamber and has this gloop injected into them so they can spend all of their time in their chamber, and some digital monster starts invading everyone's virtual reality fantasies in their chambers. Agh, my memory is so bad. Anyone, if anyone knows this series let me know, thanks!!

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LotusEaterMachine

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243568/series-where-the-protagonist-jumps-through-portals-to-stop-someone-messing-up-th (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

This is the [Pendragon Adventure series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pendragon_Adventure) by D.J. MacHale.

Uncle Press, the lead Traveler, introduces Bobby to the flumes, enchanted tubes used by Travelers to journey among the ten territories: especially eventful locations and time-periods.

The Lost City of Faar (#2) is the water world, Cloral; The Reality Bug (#4) is the VR world.

[image: cover of "The Lost City of Faar"] [image: cover of "The Reality Bug"]