# Series where the protagonist jumps through portals to stop someone messing up the timeline

Tags: story-identification, novel

My boyfriend is trying to remember a novel series he read in the early 2000s.

He describes the book as jumping through several dimensions of Earth using a portal, and having different amounts of time to stop someone from continuously messing up the timeline in each dimension.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this jumping from one time to another, or jumping from one dimension/alternate Earth to another?  Does the protagonist return to the start point between journeys, or just always travel from one to the next?

Comment: This is somewhat reminiscent of Asimov's "The End of Eternity", but it is much older than the early 2000s.  They travel not through portals but through time in something called a "kettle".  So it is a bit of a long shot -- if this sounds as though it might be a possibility, I will try to write up a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds a lot like **[Pendragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendragon:_Journal_of_an_Adventure_through_Time_and_Space) by D.J. MacHale** published from 2002 to 2009. The first point that screamed out at me was the jumping through portals to save the timeline. The protagonist, Bobby Pendragon, was trained to become a Traveler by his uncle, a group of worm-hole travelling warriors who travel between different "Territories". In the book series their job is to prevent the destruction created by the evil Saint Dane, the antagonist, who plans to destroy "what separates order from chaos"—the very fabric and structure of the universe, known as "Halla"<sup>[[1]](https://archive.org/details/merchantofdeathp00djma_0)</sup>.

The Travelers were able to use portals called "Flumes" to travel between the 10 "territories" in the Universe. The flumes travel to especially important times and places in the Universe and each territory has a resident Traveler who should look after it, Bobby is resident to the territory Second Earth (set in the Early 2000s in New York City).

Two other territories are made up of different Earth "dimensions". The three Earths are set in different points of history:

- First Earth - In 1937 at the place and during the crash of the [Hindenburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster),
- Second Earth - Early 2000s in New York City,
- Third Earth - New York City in the year 5010.

The other territories range from the ocean-wide worlds of Cloral to the deserts of Zadaa and the rainforests of Eelong.

The covers can be seen below:

[image: All 10 covers of the book series Pendragon]

Comment: Thank you so much that's the one!! He's so excited haha

Comment: @Shé-AnnCunningham Enjoy!